# How to add new menu in orange HRM

Tags: symfony-1.4, orangehrm

I have added a new menu title in the second level tab , but i don't know how to navigate to the particular href link. Please help me out with the steps.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Go to the file-/orangehrm3.1.1/symfony/plugins/orangehrmCorePlugin/lib/authorization/service/MenuService.php In this file you will find the main menu service .

Then go to the orangehrm database you will find ohrm_menu_item table and add the name of the menu you want to display.

Comment: do we need to manually add menu in ohrm_menu_item database ..?

Comment: @BenjaBoy how to redirect user to specific link or tab when he clicks on newly generated menu item in ohrm_menu_item? As it's getting displayed but it's redirecting me to same page as first level menu